# Excel VBA crashing due to size

Tags: vba

I made a script in VBA that should read a very long Pivot Table with over 190,000 entries in the "Data" sheet, and according with the value in the column "J", it should write the info from that row in a sheet called "Temp".
When the value from column "A" changes, it should read from sheet "Regioner" a list of over 600 entries and check if each value is presented in the previous arrays of values.
The code I wrote works, but it takes forever to write down the expected 220,000 entries in the "Temp" sheet. In my laptop, i5 6th generation with 8Gb RAM, it simply crashes.
The current code is as per below.
Many thanks to all!

```
Public Sub FindWithoutOrder()

Dim DataRowCounter As Long
Dim TempRowCounter As Long
Dim RegiRowCounter As Long
Dim DataOldCounter As Long
Dim DataNewCounter As Long
Dim loopCounter As Long
Dim DataOldProd As Range
Dim DataNewProd As Range
Dim DataPurchase As Range
Dim RegiButikk As Range
Dim ButikkFlag As Boolean

'Code optimization to run faster.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Initialize variables.
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DataRowCounter = 11
TempRowCounter = 1
DataOldCounter = 11
DataNewCounter = 11
Set DataOldProd = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A" & DataRowCounter)
Set DataNewProd = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A" & DataRowCounter)
Set DataPurchase = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("J" & DataRowCounter)

'Start of loop that verifies all values inside "Data" sheet.
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Do Until (IsEmpty(DataOldProd) And IsEmpty(DataNewProd))

    'Verify if the product of new line is still the same or different.
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    If DataNewProd.Value = DataOldProd.Value Then
        DataNewCounter = DataNewCounter + 1
    Else

        'Initialize variables from "Regioner" sheet.
        '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ButikkFlag = False
        RegiRowCounter = 11
        Set RegiButikk = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Regioner").Range("C" & RegiRowCounter)

        'Verify list of supermarkets and match them with purchases list.
        '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Do Until IsEmpty(RegiButikk)

            'Check all supermarkets in the product range.
            '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            For loopCounter = DataOldCounter To DataNewCounter - 1

                'Compare both entries and register them if it doesn't exist in the product list.
                '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                If RegiButikk.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("D" & loopCounter).Value Then
                    ButikkFlag = True
                    RegiRowCounter = RegiRowCounter + 1
                    Set RegiButikk = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Regioner").Range("C" & RegiRowCounter)
                    Exit For
                Else
                    ButikkFlag = False
                End If

            Next loopCounter

            'Add to list supermarkets not present in the purchases list.
            '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            If ButikkFlag = False Then
                ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Temp").Range("B" & TempRowCounter & ":D" & TempRowCounter).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Regioner").Range("A" & RegiRowCounter & ":C" & RegiRowCounter).Value
                ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Temp").Range("A" & TempRowCounter).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A" & DataRowCounter - 1).Value
                TempRowCounter = TempRowCounter + 1
                RegiRowCounter = RegiRowCounter + 1
                Set RegiButikk = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Regioner").Range("C" & RegiRowCounter)
            End If

        Loop

        'Reset the product range.
        '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        DataOldCounter = DataNewCounter
        DataNewCounter = DataNewCounter + 1

    End If

    'Validate if item was purchased in the defined period and copy it.
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    If DataPurchase.Value = 0 Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Temp").Range("A" & TempRowCounter & ":D" & TempRowCounter).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A" & DataRowCounter & ":D" & DataRowCounter).Value
        TempRowCounter = TempRowCounter + 1
    End If

    'Update row counter and values for previous and new product readed.
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Set DataOldProd = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A" & DataRowCounter)
    DataRowCounter = DataRowCounter + 1
    Set DataNewProd = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A" & DataRowCounter)
    Set DataPurchase = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("J" & DataRowCounter)

Loop

'Code optimization to run faster.
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: `'Code optimization to run faster` no it's not. There's no magic "code optimizer" instruction, in any language ever invented. Inefficient code will be inefficient, even if Excel isn't repainting itself or constantly calculating and raising worksheet events (the latter two of which are *still* happening BTW). Now, can you define "it simply crashes"? Exactly what is the problem? Going blank with a "(not responding)" header isn't *crashing*, it's entirely expected. If it's *crashing*, surely you're getting an error message - what is it?

Comment: Do you get "Not enough resources" or is that only with power pivot /chart?

Comment: Sorry for late answer. First, let me clarify the fact that I don't know how to code, never done it before, and just did for the first time based in stuff that I've found online. Please, keep that in mind... Regarding the problem, the laptop stop responding (not responding), and after more than an hour, I simply give up and force Excel to shut down!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having this code scattered all over the place:

```
'Code optimization to run faster.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

Use this procedure:

```
Public Sub ToggleWaitMode(ByVal wait As Boolean)
    Application.Cursor = IIf(wait, XlMousePointer.xlWait, XlMousePointer.xlDefault)
    Application.StatusBar = IIf(wait, "Working...", False)
    Application.Calculation = IIf(wait, XlCalculation.xlCalculationManual, XlCalculation.xlCalculationAutomatic)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = Not wait
    Application.EnableEvents = Not wait
End Sub
```

Like this:

```
Public Sub DoSomething()
    ToggleWaitMode True 
    On Error GoTo CleanFail

    'do stuff

CleanExit:
    ToggleWaitMode False
    Exit Sub
CleanFail:
    'handle errors
    Resume CleanExit
End Sub
```

Disabling automatic calculation and worksheet events should already help quite a lot... but it's by no means "optimizing" anything. It simply makes Excel work [much] less, whenever a cell is modified.

If your code works but is just slow, take it to [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) and *present it* to the VBA reviewers: they'll go out of their ways to help you *actually* optimize your code. I know, I'm one of them =)